# How to set the timeout in swift trying to catch html code?

Tags: html, swift, timeout, scrape

I'm trying too get the html code from a specific URL with this code:

```
   guard let myURL = URL(string: myURLString) else {
                print("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
                return myLinksArray
            }

            do {
                 myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL, encoding: .ascii)
                print("HTML : \(myHTMLString)")
            } catch let error {
                print("Error: \(error)")
            }
```

but in this way I'm unable to set a **timeout**. Some websites require too much time to get response.
What's the best way to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you tried :        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
   // cancel your request after 10 second .
}

Comment: What you are trying to do ? where is your request ?  can you please make its clear ? As your question if you can get response thn you can just cancel response after sometime with thiws method :  ```DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) { // cancel your request after 10 second . } ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating an URLSession [dataTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask), I believe it would be a better approach. You can create a custom `URLSessionConfiguration` and use it to specify the [timeoutIntervalForRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1408259-timeoutintervalforrequest?language=objc) or [timeoutIntervalForResource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlsessionconfiguration/1408153-timeoutintervalforresource?language=objc) according to your needs like this:

```
guard let myURL = URL(string: myURLString) else {
    print("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
    fatalError()
}

let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15 // seconds
sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 15 // seconds


let dataTask = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig).dataTask(with: myURL) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
    guard let data = data else { return }
    let myHTMLString = String(data: data, encoding: .ascii)
    print("HTML : \(myHTMLString ?? "")")
}

dataTask.resume() // start the request
```

Comment: Thank you it works! do you know by any chance how to set the user agent too?

Comment: @filiking you can change the user agent like this: `sessionConfig.httpAdditionalHeaders = ["User-Agent": "Whatever you want"]`